# Ruby inside C adding to $LOAD_PATH

Tags: c++, c, ruby, ruby-rice

Effectively I want to know if I can, purely through the use of Ruby's C library, append to $LOAD_PATH.
The reason for doing so is that I have a written an extension (using Rice but that's not super important) and I would like for it to be self contained with a few others in their own directory.

Now, I already have two working solutions that I'm fine with. The first being that I simply use the Makefile generated by Rice to install the shared object automatically into a standard directory that is already on $LOAD_PATH. Super easy no hassle. The other is that I export $RUBY_LIB as the directory I want before running and the Ruby runtime picks up on that like a champ. But what I want to know is if I can do it only in C - for reference I am looking for functionality that mimics `ruby -I./somedir`

Right now I'm initialising Ruby in C the following way, this works fine with the previously mentioned working solutions but **what I want is a way to cleanly add a directory to Ruby's $LOAD_PATH at runtime.**

```
ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
RUBY_INIT_STACK;
ruby_init();
ruby_init_loadpath();
....
rb_load_protect(...)
rb_funcall(...)
```

I could not figure out how to work with `ruby_options`, it just gave me a node and then blocked the main thread so I couldn't do anything; was I using it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the load the `$LOAD_PATH` variable, use the `rb_gv_get("$LOAD_PATH")`in your code.

The `rb_gv_get("$LOAD_PATH")` returns a Ruby array object, so any C array function can be used, such as `rb_ary_unshift`, `rb_ary_push`, etc.

For example:

```
VALUE load_path = rb_gv_get("$LOAD_PATH");
/* add a directory to Ruby's $LOAD_PATH */
rb_ary_push(load_path, rb_str_new2("any expanded directory"));
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, thanks. I wish there was a top-level method to do it but this works exactly as needed.

Comment: @cleversoap Internally, the `$LOAD_PATH` constant is registered using the `rb_define_hooked_variable` function, which register a getter method. When you use the `rb_gv_get`, you already is using the proper getter function.